# gcloud compute snapshots create VS gcloud compute disks snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, disk

Assume we have a disk called **disk-1** in the zone **us-central1-a**.

Now, what is the difference between the following two commands:

Command 1:

```
$ gcloud compute snapshots create snapshot-1 --source-disk=disk-1 --source-disk-zone=us-central1-a
```

Command 2:

```
$ gcloud compute disks snapshot disk-1 --snapshot-names=snapshot-2 --zone=us-central1-a
```

Answer (score 1):

**Command 1** :  *$ gcloud compute snapshots create snapshot-1 --source-disk=disk-1 --source-disk-zone=us-central1-a*

As per this [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/snapshots/create),  command 1 creates a snapshot of the persistent disk. Snapshots are useful for backing up persistent disk data and for creating custom images.

Command 1 will create a snapshot “snapshot-1” from a disk “disk-1” in zone “us-central1-a” i.e., In the US central1-a zone, from the disk-1 snapshot 1 will be created.

**Command 2 :**   *$ gcloud compute disks snapshot disk-1 --snapshot-names=snapshot-2 --zone=us-central1-a*

As per this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/snapshot),  command 2 also creates snapshots of persistent disks and these Snapshots can be created from persistent disks even while they are attached to running instances. Once created, snapshots may be managed (listed, deleted, etc.).  This waits until the operation returns a status of READY or FAILED, or reaches the maximum timeout, and returns the last known details of the snapshot.